# Resize and center and image with only UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to put a `400x400` image in a `UIView`.

So I created a `UIImageView` and limited the image size to `40x40`, then I placed the `UIImageView` in the centre of the `UIView`.

Now the question is, can I do that with only a `UIImageView`? The only purpose of this extra `UIView` is to set a background color and centre the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIImageView` alone cannot arbitrarily resize its image. It will respect its [`contentMode` setting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode), however. I see no particular problem doing what you've described with a `UIImageView` inside of a `UIView`. If you're set on using just a `UIImageView`, though, it could be done in at least two ways:

Option 1: In an external editor, change your 400 x 400 image into a 40 x 40 image.

Option 2: Using `UIImage`, create a smaller copy of the original 400 x 400 image in your code, so that it's 40 x 40.

After either option 1 or 2, you'll have a 40 x 40 image. Then, set your image view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeCenter`, and change the image view's `backgroundColor` to whatever you want. This will put the image in the view's center, and you can make the view itself whatever size you desire.

Answer (score 2):

`UIImageView` inherits from `UIView`.

You can set the background with `UIImageView`'s property `backgroundColor` or it's frame as well.